# Manual hairpin routing because of second router layer?

Tags: networking, router, lan, port, dd-wrt

[image]

I have a setup like this at my house. `Router A` is my ISP's router. It's the one I use for personal use, etc. `Router B` is a router for my servers which is flashed with DD-WRT.

This entire setup is meant to be very mobile. The servers are a cluster of Raspberry Pi 3s which use their integrated WiFi to connect to `Router B`. (Running a minimum installation of Debian.)

`Router B` is connected to a Dynamic DNS service to constantly update my domain with my current external IP. It broadcasts a WiFi signal, and also is connected to `Router A`'s WAP.

`Router A` assigns a static IP and forwards all ports to `Router B`. (I don't want to put `Router A` in bridge mode because I don't want all of my personal devices on the open net.)

`Router B` has some specific port forwards for `Main` and `Development` and assigns them static IPs.

The problem I have here is accessing certain services at my domain from INSIDE `Router B`'s network. Hairpin routing will obviously not work because `Router A` will "get confused" even if `Router B` is configured to do hairpin routing.

What I have been doing is adding a DNSMasq rule in DDWRT on `Router B` to send all internal requests for `MyDomain.com` to `Main`. `Main` then does some secondary routing which boils down to forwarding a few ports to `Development`.

This is kind of messy. DNSMasq does not provide me with a way to be port-specific with internal requests, but I would like `Router B` to handle 
this secondary-routing rather than `Main.`

How can I accomplish this? (Keeping in mind that as this setup is meant to be very mobile, I cannot manipulate `Router A` any further than forwarding all ports to `Router B` and assigning `Router B` a static IP.)

Comment: So just do IP based forwarding on Router B using e.g. `iptables` or set the Development branch to its own sub domain?

Comment: @Seth That's a good idea, but I'm not sure how to do this in combination with DNSMasq so that `MyDomain.com` forwards port X to 10.0.0.101 and Port X to 10.0.0.102

Comment: For this you'd have to look into port mirroring. At least if you really want the same traffic replicated two both IPs. This would usually be meant for diagnostics though and not for a live system as you wouldn't be able to tell which machine would respond to the request and/or it would need additional configuration to have the second machine accept traffic for the IP of the first one. The question would be why you redirect based on the DNS name instead of the port. Just match traffic coming from the internet based on the direction and port to Main/Development?

Comment: @Seth I'm a software engineer, not a network engineer. I didn't really understand what you said. The situation is that each server has a few services on it, some are on both, but most are not. Say I use port `22` for `Main`'s SSH and `2222` for `Development`'s SSH. I want to SPLIT the traffic, so that all requests for `MyDomain.com` on `22` go to `Main`'s IP and all requests on `2222` go to Development. This is set up from the outside, but because of the hairpin issue, it doesn't work from the inside.

Answer (score 0):

If you're able to match ports to each "Network" you could get rid of DNSMasq altogether and just use regular forwards. There are plenty of tutorial available. One would be [this](http://www.systutorials.com/816/port-forwarding-using-iptables/). What you'd be doing is setup a form NAT (network address translation).

Since DD-WRT does offer a GUI you should be able to use the GUI of the router to set this up ([example guide](https://www.flashrouters.com/blog/2012/09/14/how-to-use-port-forwarding-with-dd-wrt-routers-dd-wrt-tutorial/)). So you wouldn't even have to mess with iptables. With a general port forward you'd always redirect to said target so `RouterB:22` and `mydomain.com:22` would redirect to the same target. Hence it's probably not the best idea to redirect a port which is used by the router itself.

An alternative approach would be to use DNSMasq to just redirect `dev.mydomain.com` to the Development Network.

Comment: I'm confused. Regular port forwards don't work because the Domain always points to `Router A`'s public IP. When within `Router B`'s LAN I try and send any request to `MyDomain.com` there is never a response.

Comment: How did you setup the forward from Router A to Router B?

Comment: I just used the GUI.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Right now the access from Main to Dev and vice versa works, right? Also traffic that passes through Router A reaches Router B and is redirected to Main. So Why would it be a problem to setup Forwarding on Router B for traffic coming from Router A and do the forwarding based on the port? Your traffic between Main and Dev wouldn't be touched.

Comment: In essence what you're suggesting should be working without further configuration on the internal network, shouldn't it? I mean it works from the ourside.

Comment: Yes, it would be a rule bound to the "Internet" facing interface on your RouterB while other connections on that router wouldn't be concerned.

Comment: I am confused again. Perhaps we should open a chat?